# .net WebClient http error code

Tags: c#, .net, http, webclient

In my .net application I am working with WebClient. I have response call back something similar to:

```
private void CBMethod(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Error == null)
   {
      //Process result
   }
```

}

Now in case of error, I want to retrieve the http error code. For eg 401 for unauthorized request. I want to just get the code

Comment: do you know how to use the debugger..? set thru the code and when you get to that if statement.. inspect e. and see what other properties are exposed..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the status code from the response:

```
if (e.Error is System.Net.WebException)
{
    var webException = (System.Net.WebException)e.Error;
    var response = (System.Net.HttpWebResponse)webException.Response;

    System.Net.HttpStatusCode status = response.StatusCode;
}
```